# Unable to display TodoList view in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Iam learning Backbone JS, Iam trying to display TodosList, but not rendering. However, iam able to get collection data from the server.

Could you please tell me what went wrong in the below code.

**Here is the code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api',
})

var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TodoItem,
    url: 'api/todos'
})


var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection,'fetch',this.render)
        this.collection.fetch()
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne,this)
    },
    addOne: function(todoItem){
        console.log(todoItem.get('status'))
    }

})


var todoItem = new TodoItem()
var todoList = new TodoCollection()

var todoView = new TodoView({el: '#demo', collection: todoList})

todoView.render()

console.log(todoView.el)


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

And also Iam not sure whether 'fetch' is pre-defined event or not? When to use 'reset' event , when to use 'fetch' event? They both look similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no [`'fetch'` event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) so your `listenTo` doesn't do anything useful. Usually you'd reset the whole collection when you [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) it:

```
this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
```

and then listen for a `'reset'` event:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
```

The `reset:true` option to `fetch` tells `fetch` to completely replace the collection's content with the fetched data in one operation; then the collection will trigger a `'reset'` event when the `fetch` is all done and you're listener will convert that to a `render` call.

Your `initialize` should look more like:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
}
```